# Python 2.7 Different behavior of Multiprocess pool on Windows and Ubuntu

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu, python-multiprocessing

I use multiprocess.Pool in my program like:

```
def funA(dict,pool):
    dosomething()
    pool.app_async(somethingInDict)
if __name__==__main__:
    inf={}
    pool=Pool(4)
    process=Process(target=funA,args=(inf,pool))
    process.start()
```

this works normally in Ubuntu 17.04 with python 2.7,but in Windows 10 with python 2.7,I got a error: NotImplementedError: pool objects cannot be passed between processes or pickled.

I understand this error is caused because the object passed between process need to be pickled and pool cannot be pickled,But I wanna know why this program can run on ubuntu 17 normally.Is this about the different kernel of Windows and Linux?

Comment: it's not the answer, but move to 3.last python from 2.x

Answer (score 0):

Unix and Windows differ when it comes to process creation.

Unix uses the `fork` primitive which creates a clone of the parent process. When creating a `Process` object, the arguments are passed via inheritance as the child process has a copy of the virtual address space of the parent.

Windows instead, uses the `spawn` strategy where a brand new process is created and a new Python interpreter is loaded within. As the address space is totally different, the arguments must be serialized and sent to the child process via a `pipe`.

You can read more about process starting strategy in the [multiprocessing documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#contexts-and-start-methods).